# Linq .Sum() function fails when there is nothing to Sum

Tags: c#, linq

When running the following Linq query

```
ViewBag.AmountThisYear = db.Bookings
            .Where(p => p.Id == id && 
                        p.StartDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
            .Sum(t => t.Price);
```

I am getting the following error when there are no results  returned in the where clause

> The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the
>   materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type.

How should the Sum be written to cope with this situation

Comment: What is `Price`? Is is `Nullable` type?

Comment: What type of `id` field?

Comment: .Where(t=>t.Price.HasValue).Sum(t => t.Price);

Comment: Price is a decimal (not nullable) and Id is  an int

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since  no rows are returned you cannot sum. You could use `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
ViewBag.AmountThisYear = db.Bookings
            .Where(p => p.Id == id && 
                        p.StartDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
            .Select(t => t.Price)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
            .Sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the calculating **field is not nullable**, then you need to cast nullable first for calculation. So the change will be like this below:

```
ViewBag.AmountThisYear = db.Bookings
            .Where(p => p.Id == id && 
                        p.StartDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
            .Sum(t => (decimal?)t.Price) ?? 0m;
```

Also, add coalesce operator (??) to translate null to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal sum = 0;
var booking = db.Bookings
        .Where(p => p.Id == id && 
                    p.StartDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year);


if(bookings.Any())
{
    sum = booking.Sum(t => t.Price);
}
```

ViewBag.AmountThisYear = sum;

Comment: Works also but needs to execute the query twice.